# Jenkins: How can Jenkins simulate a log out and log back in?

Tags: docker, jenkins

In order to fix a docker issue in Jenkins, I need to run the following commands:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat   #add the tomcat user to the docker group
$ sudo service docker restart      #restart the docker service
```

The next step is to log out of the session (close the terminal window) and log back in (re-open the terminal window).  This is easy from an actual terminal window, but how do we instruct Jenkins to simulate a logout and log back in?

Comment: This is a Freestyle job.  Once I get it working in Freestyle, I'll convert it to Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to configure your user to access the docker socket. The restart of the engine isn't needed, nor is it necessary to exit the shell:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat   #add the tomcat user to the docker group
$ newgrp docker      #recognize the new group membership
```